# Building a MERN app with ability to push image to Ethereum blockchain

Tags: addresses

I am building a simple app that is like instagram but want to give the user the ability to push their image to the ethereum blockchain combined with a MERN stack.

I do not want to use metamask for this or any other browser wallet and wondering what the solution to this would be.

Essentially, I want to push data to the ethereum blockchain with addresses.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1- you can't or at least you shouldn't push images to any block chain, this will cost you a lot in gas
2- you can't send transactions without a wallet sending it
3- if you still want to use a block chain then you will need a backend where you will have a private key when you send the image to the smart contract but you will pay all the gas fees

so I suppose that what you really need is something like ipfs or arwave instead of block chain

Comment: I wouldn't push to actual blockchain, just want to have it connected. And I wouldn't say "can't" if you can lol. We can have a backend to store keys. This is more for a learning project to interact with the Ethereum blockchain. So, if we take your 3rd point, we would write a smart contract and what else? I think I am missing the backend structure aside from the smart contract.

Comment: Also, would there be a way to connect and push to a testnet instead of the mainnet?

Comment: well yes you can upload the contract in a testnet, so if you want to have the full image in the blockchain maybe you can try with upload it encoded in something like base64 or something like that